# Как сделать такую сетку на css?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, на рисунке слайдер, и в каждом квадрате один слайд с изображением.
Как сделать такую сетку на css?
В вёрстке каждый квадрат это отдельный слайд, т.е. в слайде не два ряда, а один.
Плагин слайдера сам образует два ряда через настройки и 4 в ряд.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужен именно такой слайдер или сверстать и стилизовать нужно элементы?

Comment: @nazarukroman, хотелось бы узнать, как сделать такие точки, но чтобы по краям этих точек не было

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример 1

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 25px;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 1px;
}

.item {
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 25%;
  border: 2px dotted #ccc;
  margin: -1px;
}

.item:nth-of-type(8n + 1),
.item:nth-of-type(8n + 5) {
  border-left: none;
}

.item:nth-of-type(8n + 1),
.item:nth-of-type(8n + 2),
.item:nth-of-type(8n + 3),
.item:nth-of-type(8n + 4) {
  border-top: none;
}

.item:nth-of-type(8n + 4),
.item:nth-of-type(8n + 8) {
  border-right: none;
}

.item:nth-of-type(8n + 5),
.item:nth-of-type(8n + 6),
.item:nth-of-type(8n + 7),
.item:nth-of-type(8n + 8) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Пример 2

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 25px;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

.item:before,
.item:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.item:before {
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc 16%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: left;
  background-size: 2px 14px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

.item:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc 16%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: top;
  background-size: 14px 2px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.item:nth-of-type(8n + 1):before,
.item:nth-of-type(8n + 5):before,
.item:nth-of-type(8n + 1):after,
.item:nth-of-type(8n + 2):after,
.item:nth-of-type(8n + 3):after,
.item:nth-of-type(8n + 4):after {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а подскажите, как сделать круглые точки во 2м вашем примере? благодарю за решение

Comment: @word - увы данным способом не получиться. Как вариант использовать изображение + background-repeat